# Trouble With Partitions

Tags: macos, partition

I'm trying to download an update for a program I use frequently. The program can only run on a non-case sensitive file system, so it can't run on my main partition. I partitioned a second drive that isn't case sensitive so I could download it. That partition is now completely full. I tried partitioning more space but disk utility says "This partition cannot be modified.". Below is a screen shot of disk utility. What can I do to get more space for my second partition? I tried making a third partition, that was non-case sensitive as well to try and merge them together, but disk utility says "This partition cannot be modified." Please help?

[image]

Comment: If you have a separate disk available, you could copy the contents of your second drive 'Macintosh HD 2' into it; verify the transfer, delete the original partition, recreate the partition, and copy the data back into it. Disk utility will not allow you to merge a new partition which physically precedes the partition (1,3,2) because the dynamic resizing requires them to exist on the disk in the opposite order (1,2,3).

Answer (score -1):

Thankfully I just copied everything on my second partition to my main and deleted the second partition and resized it. Thanks a lot guys.